# Why do int32_t and int16_t have same number of bits in printf output?

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  uint32_t a = 0xF0FF1FFF;
  printf("a = 0x%x\n",a);
  uint16_t b = a;
  printf("b = 0x%x\n",b);


  int32_t c = 0xF0FF8FFF;
  printf("c = 0x%x\n",c);
  int16_t d = c;
  printf("d = 0x%x\n",d);

  int32_t e = d;
  printf("e = 0x%x\n",e);

  return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
a = 0xf0ff1fff
b = 0x1fff
c = 0xf0ff8fff
d = 0xffff8fff
e = 0xffff8fff
```

In this example, why does `d` print 32 bits unlike `b`?

Comment: Because it's implicitly converted to `int`.

Comment: The `"%x"` treats the respective argument as `unsigned int`. It's UB if you pass something with a different type. Use `"%" PRIu32` for a value of type `uint32_t`. See `<inttypes.h>` https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html

Comment: @pmg: You are right.

Comment: How do I get in hexadecimal format then?

Comment: The assignment to `d` is subject to integer overflow, since the unsigned value in `c` cannot be represented as a 16-bit signed value.  That having been said, it's simply copying the low-order 16 bits, making it a negative number.  When passed to `printf`, it's promoted to a signed integer, so the high-order 16 bits are all 1 due to sign extension.  You're then trying to print it as an unsigned value, which strictly speaking requires you to cast it to `unsigned`, but it's simply showing  the sign-extended value, just as it does when you print `e` (which is also missing the `unsigned` cast).

Comment: @TomKarzes : I was trying to understand the sign extension with these examples.

Comment: @SreerajChundayil And now you do.  Just understand that `printf` is not required to do what you want when you pass an `int` to a `%x` format.  You should cast it to `unsigned` when passing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a type smaller than `int` (like e.g. `int16_t` often is) is passed to a vararg function function like `printf`, it is [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to an `int`.

This promotion includes *sign extension*, so a negative number still is the same negative number.

And using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system, when the high bit is set, that indicates a negative number. So e.g. `0xf8ff` will be promoted to `0xfffff8ff`.

This is what happens here.

To print an `int16_t` as hexadecimal, use the `PRIx16` macro from [`<inttypes.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer):

```
printf("d = %" PRIx16 "\n", d);
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to understand the sign extension with these examples. To print now I will have to cast to unsigned char* and print?

Comment: @SreerajChundayil Added example on how to print a `int16_t` value in hexadecimal form.

Comment: `PRIx16` is for `uint16_t` and should not be used with `int16_t` without converting it to `uint16_t` first. A C implementation would be within its rights (confirming to the C standard) to print a negative `int16_t` value passed for `PRIx16` with the same preceding `f` characters in OP’s example.